# Applying :hover to ::before (using li)

Tags: html, css, hover, html-lists

How do I apply `:hover` to `::before` in the following code, I have tried several different combinations  with no results. My goal to change the color of · When I hover over the link/li.

```
td.infolinks ul{
   padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
   margin: 0px;
   list-style-type: none;
}

td.infolinks ul li::before{
   content: "·";
   color: #FF6666;
   margin-right: 5px;
}

td.infolinks a:hover td.infolinks ul li::before{
   color: blue;
}
```

Comment: try `td.infolinks ul li:hover:before { color:blue; }` - please post some html if that didn't work : )

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pmLz9/

Comment: @RobSedgwick I think the OP wants something different, from the title, he may want to apply some style to the `:before` when hovering **on the `:before`** only, not when hovering **on the whole `li`** item. Your example will change the style of `:before` when hovering on the whole `li` item.

Comment: Aye Maybe, @KingKing - sounds like Op can just use list-style in all honesty .. dunno

Comment: @RobSedgwick however, we just need to use a little trick to achieve that, I've just adjusted it a little from your demo and the result is here http://jsfiddle.net/pmLz9/1/ (as far as I know the `pointer-events` is supported well by almost modern browsers - may have to add some prefix).

Comment: @KingKing, that's ace!

Comment: @RobSedgwick thank you for the help, that was so simple. And no, I didn't want to use list-style because the circle is too big, i needed something delicate looking for aesthetic purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
ul li:hover::before { color: #FF6666; }
```